# How do I switch the order of an outer index on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
data = {"Weekday": ["Sun", "Sun", "Mon", "Mon"], "city": ["Austin", "Dallas", "Austin", "Dallas"], "visitors": [139, 237, 326,456], "signups": [7,12,3,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With a multilevel index

```
df.set_index(["Weekday", "city"], inplace=True)




       visitors  signups
Weekday city                     
Sun     Austin       139        7
        Dallas       237       12
Mon     Austin       326        3
        Dallas       456        5
```

After stacking and unstacking, playing around with it, swapping levels and reindexing I end up with this:

```
          
Weekday city                     
Mon     Austin       326        3
        Dallas       456        5
Sun     Austin       139        7
        Dallas       237       12
```

How do I switch the outer index back around as in the original?

Can't figure out a simple immediate way to do it.

The closest I have gotten is with

```
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```

Which inverts both the inner and the outer which is not what I want. I just want the outer to switch.

I have also tried the following:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `result = result.reindex(original, axis=0)` does this work?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to store the 'original' index in a variable then reindex the dataframe later.

```
data = {"Weekday": ["Sun", "Sun", "Mon", "Mon"], "city": ["Austin", "Dallas", "Austin", "Dallas"], "visitors": [139, 237, 326,456], "signups": [7,12,3,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.set_index(["Weekday", "city"])
print('Original Dataframe')
print(df)
print('\n')
idx = df.index

df = df.stack().unstack()
print('Played with dataframe')
print(df)
print('\n')
df = df.reindex(idx)
print('Reindexed Dataframe')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Original Dataframe
                visitors  signups
Weekday city                     
Sun     Austin       139        7
        Dallas       237       12
Mon     Austin       326        3
        Dallas       456        5


Played with dataframe
                visitors  signups
Weekday city                     
Mon     Austin       326        3
        Dallas       456        5
Sun     Austin       139        7
        Dallas       237       12


Reindexed Dataframe
                visitors  signups
Weekday city                     
Sun     Austin       139        7
        Dallas       237       12
Mon     Austin       326        3
        Dallas       456        5
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I was just wondering what would the format be for this idx variable. I think that is where I was struggling. I'm not very good with reindex.

Comment: I don't understand you question.  `idx =  df.index` stores the index of that dataframe at that point in time, then once you alter the order of that index, you can use reindex to "reorder" the dataframe as long as the index structure is the same.

Comment: Ok got it Thanks so much Scott